# Efficient transfer of console data, tar & gzip/ bzip2 without creating intermediary files

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, tar, bzip2

Linux environment. So, we have this program 't_show', when executed with an ID will write price data for that ID on the console. There is no other way to get this data.

I need to copy the price data for IDs 1-10,000 between two servers, using minimum bandwidth, minimum number of connections. On the destination server the data will be a separate file for each id with the format:

```
<id>.dat
```

Something like this would be the long-winded solution:

dest:

```
files=`seq 1 10000`
for id in `echo $files`;
do
    ./t_show $id > $id
done
tar cf - $files | nice gzip -c  > dat.tar.gz
```

source:

```
scp user@source:dat.tar.gz ./
gunzip dat.tar.gz
tar xvf dat.tar
```

That is, write each output to its own file, compress & tar, send over network, extract.

It has the problem that I need to create a new file for each id. This takes up tonnes of space and doesn't scale well.

Is it possible to write the console output directly to a (compressed) tar archive without creating the intermediate files? Any better ideas (maybe writing compressed data directly across network, skipping tar)?

The tar archive would need to extract as I said on the destination server as a separate file for each ID.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: As an aside, avoid the Useless Use of Echo in Backticks.  The idiomatic way to code that is `for id in $files; ...`

Comment: Is the data such that it cannot simply be transmitted as a single big text file?  By the sounds of it, you could just create a single CSV file on standard output with "id","price" for each id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all

I've taken the advice 'just send the data formatted in some way and parse it on the the receiver', it seems to be the consensus. Skipping tar and using ssh -C for simplicity.

Perl script. Breaks the ids into groups of 1000. IDs are source_id in hash table. All data is sent via single ssh, delimited by 'HEADER', so it writes to the appropriate file. This is a *lot* more efficient:

```
sub copy_tickserver_files {
my $self = shift;

my $cmd = 'cd tickserver/ ; ';

my $i = 1;

while ( my ($source_id, $dest_id) = each ( %{ $self->{id_translations} } ) ) {
    $cmd .= qq{ echo HEADER $source_id ; ./t_show $source_id ; };
    $i++;
    if ( $i % 1000 == 0 ) {
        $cmd = qq{ssh -C dba\@$self->{source_env}->{tickserver} " $cmd " | };
        $self->copy_tickserver_files_subset( $cmd );
        $cmd = 'cd tickserver/ ; ';
    }
}

$cmd = qq{ssh -C dba\@$self->{source_env}->{tickserver} " $cmd " | };
$self->copy_tickserver_files_subset( $cmd );

}

sub copy_tickserver_files_subset {
my $self = shift;
my $cmd = shift;

my $output = '';
open TICKS, $cmd;
while(<TICKS>) {
    if ( m{HEADER [ ] ([0-9]+) }mxs ) {
        my $id = $1;
        $output = "$self->{tmp_dir}/$id.ts";
        close TICKSOP;
        open TICKSOP, '>', $output;
        next;
    }
    next unless $output;
    print TICKSOP "$_";
}
close TICKS;
close TICKSOP;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just send the data formatted in some way and parse it on the the receiver.

foo.sh on the sender:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( id = 0; id <= 10000; id++ ))
do
    data="$(./t_show $id)"
    size=$(wc -c <<< "$data")

    echo $id $size
    cat <<< "$data"
done
```

On the receiver:

```
ssh -C user@server 'foo.sh'|while read file size; do
    dd of="$file" bs=1 count="$size"
done
```

`ssh -C` compresses the data during transfer

Comment: Thanks for that. That is the method I went for- skipping tar & gzip and parsing data over a single connection. I'll post the can when possible

Answer (score 1):

You can at least `tar` stuff over a ssh connection:

```
tar -czf - inputfiles | ssh remotecomputer "tar -xzf -"
```

How to populate the archive without intermediary files however, I don't know.

**EDIT:** Ok, I suppose you could do it by writing the tar file manually. The header is specified [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29#File_header) and doesn't seem too complicated, but that isn't exactly my idea of convenient...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is working with a plain bash script. But you could have a look at the `Archive::TAR` module for perl or other scripting languages.

The Perl Module has a function [`add_data`](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Archive-Tar-1.76/lib/Archive/Tar.pm#%24tar-%3Eadd_data_%28_%24filename,_%24data,_%5b%24opthashref%5d_%29) to create a "file" on the fly and add it to the archive for streaming accros the network.

The Documentation is found here:

Answer (score 0):

You can do better without tar:

```
#!/bin/bash
for id in `seq 1 1000`
do
    ./t_show $id
done | gzip
```

The only difference is that you will not get the boundaries between different IDs.

Now put that in a script, say `show_me_the_ids` and do from the client

```
shh user@source ./show_me_the_ids | gunzip
```

And there they are!

Or either, you can specify the `-C` flag to compress the SSH connection and remove the gzip / gunzip uses all together.

If you are really into it you may try `ssh -C`,  `gzip -9` and other compression programs. 
Personally I'll bet for `lzma -9`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
(for ID in $(seq 1 10000); do echo $ID: $(/t_show $ID); done) | ssh user@destination "ImportscriptOrProgram"
```

This will print "1: ValueOfID1" to standardout, which  a transfered via ssh to the destination host, where you can start your importscript or program, which reads the lines from standardin.

HTH